# layoutAnimation works only one time

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview

I have a `LinearLayout` with `layoutAnimation` property that is used for a customize `ExpandableListView`. like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layoutAnimation="@drawable/list_layout_controller"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

When I click on the list, the animation will be displayed. But it works only once and it will not animate the list in the next click. Why?

Please let me know, If you need more description.

Thank you

Comment: by click u mean expand and collapse a item..?

Comment: Yes, expand and collapse a item

Comment: Can you paste the list_layout_contorller? Are you extending the ExpandableListView or created a new one? Need to see some code..

Comment: try calling `requestLayout()` on the view in `onClickListener`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Layout Animations are run when views are added to the layout. So you will have to manually add/remove the views on every expand/collapse for the layout animation to work.

For this, you can maintain a Map of views with the list index as the key.
Every time you get click, just pick the corresponding items from the map and add to your layout. The animation will run on that view and your problem is fixed.

You can also try by changing the visibility of views in `onClick()`. But not sure about this.
Try and let me know.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. This line helped me : `Layout Animations are run when views are added to the layout`

Comment: Thanks for the hint to change visiblilty: I'm using a `LayoutAnimationController` which also fired only once. Now I just set the Layout visibility to `GONE`, in the next statement I set it to `VISIBLE` and in the following statement I write `myLayout.setLayoutAnimation(myLayoutAnimController);` Works perfectly :-)

Comment: @Ronnie: Right now I'm trying to animate(slide from right to left) the recyclerview (with card view as a child) using layout animation on activity launch. how do I animate in the opposite direction(slide from left to right) when I close the activity?

Answer (score 9):

First u want to declare

```
Animation  listanimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mainActivity.this, R.anim.list_layout_controller);
```

and everytime `clearAnimation` first.
In clickevent of LinearLayout

```
 linearLayout.clearAnimation();
 linearLayout.startAnimation(listanimation);
```

Answer (score 3):

call

listView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();

before all changes in the list

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart animation on each item click:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      view.getAnimation().start();
      //your custom logic
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
public void startLayoutAnimation ()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#startLayoutAnimation()